# Pandas: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas

My code looks like this:

```
for index, row in df_csv_mk.iterrows():
    exp1_high= df_metrics[df_metrics.time == row['time1_high']]['absolute exposure']
    exp1_high = exp1_high.values
    df_exposure_mkresult=df_exposure_mkresult.append({'exp1_high': exp1_high}, ignore_index=True)
```

and my the resulting dataframe:

```
exp1_high   
0   []  
1   []  
2   [0.00666628]    
3   [0.00674054]    
4   [0.00661782]    
5   [0.0066166]
6   [0.00660748]    
7   [0.00645245]    
8   [0.006456]
```

From what I see it is a column made of arrays, but when I try to extract the element of one array (exp1_high[0]) I receive the error  (index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0)... any help? Please do not put it as duplicates, I already tried the other solutions on other questions... thanks!

The following full error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-757-47395f0c238c> in <module>
     10     exp1_high= df_metrics[df_metrics.time == row['time1_high']]['absolute exposure']
     11     exp1_high = exp1_high.values
---> 12     print(exp1_high[0])
     13     df_exposure_mkresult=df_exposure_mkresult.append({'exp1_high': exp1_high}, ignore_index=True)
     14 

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: `I receive the above error... any help?` which error!! Please update

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, the error is in the title of the question...

Comment: put error in question and put FULL text - starting at work `Traceback`

Comment: OK if you want..

Comment: It seems like `exp1_high` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df_csv_mk.iterrows():
    exp1_high= df_metrics[df_metrics.time == row['time1_high']]['absolute exposure']
    exp1_high = exp1_high.values
    if exp1_high.size == 0:
        df_exposure_mkresult=df_exposure_mkresult.append({'exp1_high': 0}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        df_exposure_mkresult=df_exposure_mkresult.append({'exp1_high': exp1_high[0]}, ignore_index=True)
```

The first two rows were empty...